# Laravel Ajax submit multiple row data

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, laravel, laravel-5

I am doing new reg processing with mass data through `Ajax`.

`Laravel 5.7.28`

`PHP version 7.2`

[image]
■ Press the + Button on the right side of the image to add items.

rows data can not be sent at some time.

after my examined,

there is no problem if the submit item is 166 or less, error message was issued when submit item is 167 or more.
I don't know what the problem is, please tell me how to solve it.

submit item is 166 or less
[image]

submit item 167 or more.
[image]

relate code

**Route**

```
Route::resource('ajax-crud', 'AjaxCrudController');
```

**Controllers**

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\AjaxCrud;
use Validator;

class AjaxCrudController extends Controller
{
    //skip...

    /**
     * Store Form view
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function create()
    {
        return view('ajax_create_items');
    }

    /**
     * Ajax Store a newly created resource in storage.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function store(Request $request)
    {
        if(request()->ajax())
        {
        //show request input data
        dd($request->input());
        //create process
        //skip...
        }
    }
    //skip...

}
```

**ajax_create_items.blade**

```
<html>
    <head>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <title>Laravel </title>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
        <script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.12/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.12/js/dataTables.bootstrap.min.js"></script>  
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.12/css/dataTables.bootstrap.min.css" />
        <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>

        <div class="container-fluid">

            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-12">
                    <div class="panel panel-default">
                        <div class="panel-heading"><h3 class="panel-title">Add Items</h3></div>
                        <div class="panel-body">

                            <form name="add_item" id="add_item" class="form-inline">
                                {{ csrf_field() }}

                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label for="pr_form_number">PR Form Number: </label>
                                    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="pr_number" value="" readonly required><br><br>
                                </div>

                                <div class="table-responsive">
                                    <table class='table table-bordered table-hover' id="tab_logic">
                                        <thead>
                                            <tr class='info'>
                                                <th style='width:10%;'>ITEM NO.</th>
                                                <th style='width:10%;'>QTY</th>
                                                <th style='width:10%;'>UNIT</th>
                                                <th style='width:30%;'>DESCRIPTION</th>
                                                <th style='width:10%;'>COST PER UNIT</th>
                                                <th style='width:10%;'>COST PER ITEM</th>
                                                <th style='width:10%;'>ACTION</th>
                                            </tr>
                                        </thead>
                                        <thead>
                                            <tr id="addr0">
                                                <td class="custom-tbl"><input class='form-control input-sm'style='width:100%;' type="text" value="1" id="pr_item0" name="pr_item[]" readonly required></td>
                                                <td class="custom-tbl"><input class='form-control input-sm' style='width:100%;' type="text" id="pr_qty0" oninput='multiply(0);' name="pr_qty[]"></td>
                                                <td class="custom-tbl"><input class='form-control input-sm' style='width:100%;' type="text" id="pr_unit0" name="pr_unit[]"></td>
                                                <td class="custom-tbl"><input class='form-control input-sm' style='width:100%;' type="text" id="pr_desc0" name="pr_desc[]"></td>
                                                <td><input class='form-control input-sm' style='width:100%;' type="text" id="pr_cpu0" oninput='multiply(0);' name="pr_cpu[]"></td>
                                                <td class="custom-tbl"><input class='estimated_cost form-control input-sm' id="pr_cpi0" style='width:100%;' type="text" name="pr_cpi[]" readonly></td>
                                                <td class="custom-tbl"><button type="button" id="add" class="btn btn-info btn-sm"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></span></button></td>
                                            </tr>
                                        </thead>
                                        <tbody id="dynamic_field">

                                        <tbody>
                                        <tfoot>
                                            <tr class='info'>
                                                <td style='width:65%;text-align:right;padding:4px;' colspan='5'>GRAND TOTAL:</td>
                                                <td style='padding:0px;'>

                                                    <input style='width:100%;' type='text' class='form-control input-sm' id='grand_total' name='grand_total' value='0' readonly required>

                                                </td>

                                        </tfoot>

                                    </table>
                                </div>


                                <button type="button" id="submit" name="submit" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
                            </form>

                        </div>

                    </div>
                </div>

            </div>


        </div>

        <script type="text/javascript">



$(document).ready(function () {
    var i = 1;


    $('#add').click(function () {
        i++;
        $('#dynamic_field').append('<tr id="row' + i 
                + '" class="dynamic-added"><td class="custom-tbl"><input id="pr_item' + i 
                + '" class="form-control input-sm"style="width:100%;" type="text" value="' + i 
                + '" name="pr_item[]" readonly required></td><td class="custom-tbl"><input id="pr_qty' + i 
                + '"class="form-control input-sm" style="width:100%;" type="text" oninput="multiply(' + i 
                + ');" name="pr_qty[]"></td><td class="custom-tbl"><input id="pr_unit' + i 
                + '"class="form-control input-sm" style="width:100%;" type="text" name="pr_unit[]"></td><td class="custom-tbl"><input id="pr_desc' + i 
                + '" class="form-control input-sm" style="width:100%;" type="text" name="pr_desc[]"></td><td class="custom-tbl"><input id="pr_cpu' + i 
                + '" class="form-control input-sm" style="width:100%;" type="text" oninput="multiply(' + i 
                + ');" name="pr_cpu[]"></td><td class="custom-tbl"><input id="pr_cpi' + i 
                + '" class="estimated_cost form-control input-sm" style="width:100%;" type="text" name="pr_cpi[]" readonly></td><td class="custom-tbl"><button type="button" name="remove" id="' + i 
                + '" class="btn btn-danger btn-sm btn_remove"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></span></button></td></tr>');
    });


    $(document).on('click', '.btn_remove', function () {
        var button_id = $(this).attr("id");
        $('#row' + button_id + '').remove();
    });

    $.ajaxSetup({
        headers: {
            'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
        }
    });


    $('#submit').click(function () {
        $.ajax({
            url: "{{route('ajax-crud.store')}}",
            method: "POST",
            data: $('#add_item').serialize(),
            type: 'json',

        });
    });

});




        </script>

        <script type="text/javascript">
            function multiply(id)
            {
                var total1 = parseFloat($('#pr_qty' + id).val()) * parseFloat($('#pr_cpu' + id).val());
                $("input[id=pr_cpi" + id + "]").val(total1);
                grandTotal();
            }
            function grandTotal()
            {
                var items = document.getElementsByClassName("estimated_cost");
                var itemCount = items.length;
                var total = 0;
                for (var i = 0; i < itemCount; i++)
                {
                    total = total + parseFloat(items[i].value);
                }
                document.getElementById('grand_total').value = total;
            }
        </script>

    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Can you post the error message ? or line error ?

Comment: Take a look at the `kernel.php` file. How many requests are you allowed to send in how much time? It's weird that there is no error message but it's probably Laravel kicking in when you send too much requests in too little time.